# Efficiency of the script (finding a pair of integers which have the same remainder)

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space

I am trying to find a pair (x,y) in A such that x-y = 0 (mod n) where inputs are a positive integer n, a set A of m nonnegative integers and m > n. To run the code below I took an m and n just for the sake of running an example.

Below is the script I have written.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to write the script

```
import numpy as np import sys

n = 10 
m = 12

def functi(n, m):

  A = [0] * m

  for i in range(m):

    A[i] = np.random.randint(0,34)
   

  X = [-1] * n


  for i in range(len(A)-1,-1,-1) :  #loop backwards
    a = A[i]
    A.pop(i)
    r = a % n

    if X[r] == -1:
      X[r] = a
    else:
     return(X[r], a)
  

pair = functi(n, m) 
print(pair)
```

Comment: You ask at least three questions. A question should be *one* question. Now it will probably get closed.

Comment: Okay thanks, let me fix it

Answer (score 2):

Note that your function doesn't have the parameters described by the problem -- it should take `n` and `A` as parameters, not take an `m` and generate its own `A`.

The problem is much easier if you look at it as simply "find a pair of numbers with the same value mod n".  An simple approach to this is to bucket all of the numbers according to their value `% n`, and return a bucket once it has two numbers in it.  That way you don't need to compare each pair of values individually to see if they match.

```
>>> import random
>>> def find_equal_pair_mod_n(n, A):
...     assert len(A) > n
...     mods = {}
...     for i in A:
...         xy = mods.setdefault(i % n, [])
...         xy.append(i)
...         if len(xy) > 1:
...             return tuple(xy)
...
>>> find_equal_pair_mod_n(10, [random.randint(0, 34) for _ in range(12)])
(26, 6)
>>> find_equal_pair_mod_n(10, [random.randint(0, 34) for _ in range(12)])
(30, 10)
>>> find_equal_pair_mod_n(10, [random.randint(0, 34) for _ in range(12)])
(32, 32)
>>> find_equal_pair_mod_n(10, [random.randint(0, 34) for _ in range(12)])
(1, 1)
>>> find_equal_pair_mod_n(10, [random.randint(0, 34) for _ in range(12)])
(28, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for the note for the parameters. So in the worst case the time complexity would be the same, O(n) right? Because A has length m, so we still would need to loop m times in the worst case. Is it better in space complexity then? Would the time complexity differ if we know that n is a constant?

Comment: Now that I look closely at your original code, I think it's doing a similar sort of thing in a more confusing way (using a fixed-size list instead of a dict of lists), so yeah, the time complexity is the same (linear).

Comment: `The problem is much easier if you look at it as simply "find a pair of numbers with the same value mod n"` isn't that exactly what they're doing already? They even say so in the title, no?