# Complexity of the script

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am trying to find a pair (x,y) in A such that x-y = 0 (mod n)

Below is the script I have written.

What would be the run time complexity **if n is a constant**? --> So, this is asked but isn't n a constant anyway? I am a bit confused, the question says "inputs are a positive integer n..."

```
def find_equal_pair_mod_n(n, A):
  assert len(A) > n

  X = [-1] * n
  print(X)

  for i in range(len(A)-1,-1,-1) :  #loop backwards
    print(i)
    a = A[i]
    print(a)
    print(len(A))
    A.pop(i)
    r = a % n

    if X[r] == -1:
      X[r] = a
    else:
     return(X[r], a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiency of the script (finding a pair of integers which have the same remainder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70817590/efficiency-of-the-script-finding-a-pair-of-integers-which-have-the-same-remaind)

Comment: O(M), as you have to check all M elements

Comment: @JonSG Actually no, someone suggested I separated the questions (because I should be asking one at a time). Both are mine but the other one is more about writing efficient code, and this one is about complexity.

I still don't have an answer to my question about time complexity, which is  "the complexity if n is a constant"

Comment: @sahasrara62 you are mistaken. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

1. "What is the run time complexity in terms of `n` and `m`?". The correct answer is `O(n)`.
2. "What would be the run time complexity if `n` is a constant?". The correct answer is `O(1)`.

### Explanation

1. When you iterate over your loop, you can't do more than `n + 1` iterations, because there are only `n` different remainders when divided by `n`. So you definitely find the answer in `n + 1` or fewer iterations.
2. If `n` is constant, you are still need `n + 1` or fewer iterations to find the answer, so you need a constant time to solve your problem.